# Using Xamarin.Forms and SkiaSharp, is it possible to use an image rather than a color to stroke/fill a path?

Tags: xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I'm able to render a path and stroke/fill it with a solid color:

```
        SKPaint green = new SKPaint
        {
            Style = SKPaintStyle.StrokeAndFill,
            Color = SKColors.LimeGreen,                 
            StrokeWidth = 1,
            IsAntialias = true
        };

        canvas.Clear();
        SKPath path = new SKPath();

        // here I define my path

        canvas.DrawPath(path, green);
```

But what if I want to use a small PNG as my "texture" for the stroke/fill rather than a color?  For example, if I have a small PNG file of green grass/lawn and I want to fill the path with this PNG as the texture?  In the old Xamarin.iOS world, this was fairly simple to do.

Is this possible to do using SkiaSharp?

Comment: see discussion [here](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/667) about creating an SKPaint using a Bitmap - that might be similar to what you need

Comment: Thanks - I found that link during my initial search -- unfortunately it didn't address what the poster was trying to do.

Comment: it didn't address what THEY wanted, but it sounds like it might do what YOU want.  If you can create an SKPaint from a bitmap you should be able to use it as a fill

Comment: I actually tried what they suggested, and it worked fine if I only had one path.  However, I have up to a dozen different paths that need to be rendered, and for each I would prefer to use an image (for the texture) rather than a color.  I'm actually trying to do something similar to the poster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9647627e-029d-4b63-bfb6-a247deee1bef/is-there-a-way-to-hatch-fill-a-rectangle?forum=xamarinlibraries.

Basically you do the following:

1. create an SKBitmap from the image file
2. create an SKShader from the SKBitmap
3. assign the "Shader" property of your SKPaint to #2

Example:

```
        // Load bitmap
        string resourceID = "myImage.png";
        Assembly assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

        SKBitmap bitmap;
        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceID))
        {
            bitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(stream);
        }

        // Create the SKShader
        SKShader shader = SKShader.CreateBitmap(bitmap, SKShaderTileMode.Repeat, SKShaderTileMode.Repeat);

        // Create SKPaint
        SKPaint myPaint = new SKPaint
        {
            Style = SKPaintStyle.StrokeAndFill,
            Shader = shader
        };
```